# localhost and cross domain request

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to understand JSONP and when to use it.  I wrote the below code and am able to get data back from the service call, why doesn't it get blocked?  As I'm running it from my local machine, trying to request data from another machine, shouldn't that violate the Same Origin policy?  I'm not using JSONP below, so I thought this would get blocked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/robconery',
        type: 'GET',
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#name").text(data.login);
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="name"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONP inserts a script tag, much like just including a script from anywhere on the web, for instance

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you wouldn't see any issues with that, even if it's on Google's domain.
JSONP is the same thing, it inserts the script tag, and circumvents the same-origin policy that way.

Inside the file, the JSON is wrapped in a function, and when the script has loaded, that function is called to return the JSON etc. that's why the JSON is wrapped in a javascript function.

jQuery neatly wraps JSONP into it's ajax functionality, so it's not immediately apparent what's happening, but it's not really ajax at all.

As a sidenote, the request you're doing to Github is **NOT** JSONP, you've set the datatype to `json` so it's just regular JSON, but Github circumvents the same-origin policy by using a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: I understand I did not make a JSONP request, I purposely used JSON, because I thought that JSON would get rejected, since I'm requesting it from my localhost.  So by using Access-control-Allow-Origin, Github allowed it, without that would the JSON request have been blocked?

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing a couple of things here.

**What is JSONP?**

[**JSONP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is a way to retrieve data without being affected by the Same Origin Policy. That's because JSONP is nothing but including a `<script>` dynamically, and `<script>`s are not subject to SOP.

**What is subject to SOP?**

Ajax requests (i.e. [`XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)).

---

#### However, you are not using JSONP!

You never tell jQuery to make a JSONP request! That would be `dataType: "jsonp"`, not `dataType: "json"`. The latter just tells jQuery to process the response from the *Ajax* request as JSON.

**So, why does it still work?**

The server has to possibility to disable the SOP ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), by setting a specific header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

And that's exactly what the GitHub API is doing.

Comment: that means if i leave datatype blank JSONP request will be made automatically??

Comment: No, not at all. jQuery only uses JSONP if you explicitly tell it to use it.

Comment: "You never tell jQuery to make a JSONP request!" What does this mean?

Comment: @FelixKling - unless you're using `$.getJSON`, which figures it out automagically.

Comment: @adeneo: Only if you put something like `callback=?` in the URL.

Comment: @KnightRider: One either has to use `data: 'jsonp'` or include something like `callback=?` in the URL so that jQuery will include a `<script>` element instead of using `XMLHTTPRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

This works because the github API includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` response header.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the OP is not doing a JSONP request at all. If it was JSONP, it would just work, no need for those headers.